# Shuffle js categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, shuffle

I create a simple task manager. I want to use shuffle js to sorting task. One task can have a many category but when I create task with for example 2 categories I get 2 li list with each category.I try pass this category in array but doesn't work. Can someone help me ?
It's my code

```
 <ul class="portfolio-sorting">
                @foreach( $categories as $category )
                    <li><a href="#" data-group="{{ $category->name }}">{{$category->name }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
 </ul>
```

and li where i try pass data in array

```
 <li class="picture-item" data-groups='[{{ $category->name }}]' data-date-created="{{ $task->created_at }}" data-title="{{ $task->title }}" >
```

I want when create a task with 2 categories one li with 2 categories passes in array not two li with each categories.